# Java adding items from an INT array to a String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

```
public static String fibonacci(int a, int b){

        int max = 10;
        String returnValue;

        int[] result = new int[max];
        result[0] = a;
        result[1] = b;
                for (int i1 = 2; i1 < max; i1++) {
                    result[i1] = result[i1 - 1] + result[i1 - 2];
                }
                for (int i3 = 0; i3 < max; i3++) {
                    //Here you can do something with all the values in the array one by one
                    //Maybe make something like this?:
                    int TheINTthatHasToBeAdded = result[i3];
                    //The line where TheINTthatHasToBeAdded gets added to the String returnValue

                }           


        return returnValue;

    }
```

### -

-

The result array has items that are INTEGERS, returnValue is a string.

My question is; how do I add the items that are in the result array, to the returnValue array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to return a String containing all the fibonaci numbers you found?
If you are, change the following:

```
StringBuilder returnValue = new new StringBuilder()
```

Add the following to your 2nd loop

```
returnValue.append(result[i3]).append(",");
```

Change the return value to:

```
return returnValue.toString();
```

This should solve it (With an extra ',' in the end)

Comment: Yes thanks, I could solve this problem aswell with a simple if-statement within the for-loop to check if the i3 has reached the max int.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an array into a `String` you can use [`java.util.Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-):

```
returnValue = java.util.Arrays.toString(result);
```

Still, returning a `String` representation of the calculated array is not a good design. It would be better to return the `int[]` and let the client to convert this into a `String` or another way to consume it or display it to the user.

This is how the method may look:

```
//changed the return type from String to int[]
public static int[] fibonacci(int a, int b) {
    int max = 10;
    int[] result = new int[max];
    result[0] = a;
    result[1] = b;
    for (int i1 = 2; i1 < max; i1++) {
        result[i1] = result[i1 - 1] + result[i1 - 2];
    }
    return result;
}

//in client method, like main
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //store the result of fibonacci method in a variable
    int[] fibonacciResult = fibonacci(0, 1);
    //print the contents of the variable using Arrays#toString
    System.out.println("Fibonacci result:" + Arrays.toString(fibonacciResult));
}
```

Or even use another way to consume the results. Here's another example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //store the result of fibonacci method in a variable
    int[] fibonacciResult = fibonacci(0, 1);
    //print the contents of the variable using Arrays#toString
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < fibonacciResult.length; i++) {
        sb.append(fibonacciResult[i])
            .append(' ');
    }
    System.out.println("Fibonacci result:" + sb.toString());
}
```